# Select all rows and deselect all rows option in listview

Tags: android, listview, selectall

I have a list view with a check box in each row to select that row... And i have a select all check box above the listview to select all the rows at a click and vice versa...
is it possible to do so...

Comment: You've prolly made a Custom Adapter...just add a special function for `select all` that enables all checkboxes inside your adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListItem item = default(ListItem);
foreach ( item in MyListView.ListItems) {
    item.Selected = true;
}
```

you can use checkbox id instead of item and set it checked or vice versa.

Answer (score 18):

You can resolve this even easier by simply using 2 methods.

```
listView.clearChoices();
listView.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 2):

The object ListView has a method called clearChoices().